# save csv file in postgres database using flask

Tags: python, reactjs, csv, flask

i want to save my csv file in database using flask. in frontend i wrote a function to send the csv file to backend. here is the code:

```
    saveCsvFile = () => { 
         console.log('saveCsvFile ...', this.state.csvFile);
         axios.post( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/SalesLead/saveCsv', {
            'csv_file':this.state.csvFile,
                },  {}  )

               };

  <form>
   <input onChange={this.fileHandler} type="file" accept=".csv,text/csv" />
   <button onClick={() => this.saveCsvFile()} type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

And i wrote a simple function to read the csv file in python(flask). here is the code:

```
@SalesLeadController.route('/saveCsv', methods=['POST'])

def upload_csv():

    print('upload_csv')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        csv_file = request.files['file']

        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

        for row in csv_reader:

            user = SalesLead(username=row[0], email=row[1])

            db.session.add(user)

            db.session.commit()

        return Response(json.dumps({'status': 'success', 'message': 'data successfully saved.'}), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

But i am getting this error after uploading the CSV file:

```
400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file'
```

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<input onChange={this.fileHandler} type="file" accept=".csv,text/csv" name = "file" />
</form>
```

Since you are doing,

```
csv_file = request.files['file']
```

Here the string 'file' is the key, where the value is the actual file uploaded. The key is the name specified in the input tag in HTML

Comment: Its not working. I am still getting this error in the console `POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/SalesLead/saveCsv 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add the attribute on the form:
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`